# NextJs + Auth0: Where to put my cutom login route?

Tags: node.js, next.js, routes, auth0

I have integrated Auth0 into my NextJs project, according to the [auth0 documentation](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0#app-router), I have a folder structure looks like this:

```
- app
  - api
    - auth
      - [auth0]
        - route.js
```

Now I would like to also implement my own authentication routes into the app, where should I put my custom_auth folder?

To organize everything related to auth under the same folder, I create a folder structure looks like this:

```
- app
  - api
    - auth
      - [auth0]
        - route.js
      - custom_auth
        - login
          - route.js
        - logout
          - route.js
```

Can I put a static route next to a dynamic route? If not, what is the best practice to organize the folders for my own authentication routes?